# is there any difference between numpy.matrix and np.asmatrix?

Tags: python, numpy

both numpy.matrix and np.asmatrix could be used to construct a matrix.

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
print(np.matrix(a))
print(np.asmatrix(a))
```

is there any difference between numpy.matrix and np.asmatrix?

Comment: [docs](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asmatrix.html)

Comment: You should use `np.array()`, `np.asarray()` and `np.asanyarray()`

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asmatrix.html
'Unlike matrix, asmatrix does not make a copy if the input is already a matrix or an ndarray. Equivalent to matrix(data, copy=False).'

Answer (score 1):

to complement [@ToodlePip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56887245/5052365), here's an example that shows the different behavior:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2)
matrix = np.matrix(a)
asmatrix = np.asmatrix(a)

a[1, 1] = 999

print(matrix)
print(asmatrix)
```